# Encoding a URL string according to RFC 1738 using Go

Tags: twitter, encoding, go, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to send a request to Twitter through my Go application, and Twitter's API requires that you encode the consumer key and secret according to [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738). Is there a Go function built to do this? From what I see in the net/url package, Go uses [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) by default, and I don't see any functions on http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/ that would allow me to convert to RFC 1738.

As a heads-up, I know that RFC 3986 is newer and obsoletes 1738, but the Twitter API asks specifically for RFC 1738 so I figured I should try to do that to avoid possibly getting screwed over by a corner case. For clarification, I'm talking about part 1 of the "Issuing application-only requests" section on this page: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

Comment: The twitter documentation you cite only references RFC1728 in regard to url-encoding, which is unchanged. (also, RFC3986 does not obsolete RFC1738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) updates [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738). You can comply with RFC 1738 by complying with RFC 3986, and therefore achieve what Twitter expects.

So the [net/url](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) package should fully meet your needs.

Comment: "_You can comply with RFC 1738 by complying with RFC 3986_" is incorrect, as I've shown in the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71119582/839733).